# Android support-v4 library being added with appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

In my build gradle file I have two dependencies (appcompat-v7 and design) and then whatever externar jar files I add to the project

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

Is it normal to find in the project libraries (Project structure -> Libraries) the external jar files, appcompat-v7, design-22.2.1, support-v4 and support-annotations-22.2.1, I don't understand why the two last ones are being added, I think they're the cause of another issue I'm having (dexDebug).

Would anyone know if that is normal ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running `./gradlew -q app:dependencies` shows that `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` depends on `com.android.support:support-v4`, so that is why it is pulled in. You will have to find a separate solution for your dex debug issue.